# Wordpress wp_enqueue stylesheet with media query

Tags: php, wordpress, css, query-optimization

I use a media query in my html to load a new stylesheet for the grid if needed. Can I translate this to work within my functions.php?

```
wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/1140.css" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 1200px)" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) in the WordPress Codex, the last parameter in particular has to do with the CSS media.

```
wp_enqueue_style('html5blank', false, array(), false, 'all and (min-width: 1200px)');
```

Comment: That was a lot simpler than i thought it would be. Many thanks